# How to close a TextField numeric keyboard on iOS after editing?

Tags: codenameone

I would like to edit a numeric decimal value like 21.7 and enable the user to close the numeric keyboard (iOS 13.3.1, iPhone Xr) when done.

I'm using a numeric text field (`TextField` with constraint `TextArea.DECIMAL`). I've NOT set the option `putClientProperty("iosHideToolbar", Boolean.TURE)` for the TextField. However, there is no keyboard Done option, so the user cannot close the keyboard after entering the value.

I've gone through the documentation (https://www.codenameone.com/manual/components.html) and as I understood it, using `tf.putClientProperty("iosHideToolbar", Boolean.TRUE);` would hide the toolbar, so since I'm NOT setting the property, I assume the toolbar and the Done button should be available.

Any advice on how to get the Done button (or other ways to getting rid of the numeric keyboard)?

Answer (score 1):

In the action listener for the text field you can just invoke `stopEditing()` on the text field. You can use either the standard action listener or the done listener for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, bit what I’m looking for is not a programmatic solution, but the Done button on (or rather above, in the ios Input Accessory View) the keyboard so the user himself can close the keyboard when done. By the way, I just noticed that there is no Done button shown for a multi-line TextField with normal text, so it seems your documentation is not complete

Comment: @user1246562 Maybe the cause of your issue is elsewhere. See my answer.

Comment: What sort of build hints and theme constants do you have defined?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to edit a numeric decimal value like 21.7 and enable the
>   user to close the numeric keyboard (iOS 13.3.1, iPhone Xr) when done.
>
> I'm using a numeric text field (`TextField` with constraint
>   `TextArea.DECIMAL`). I've NOT set the option
>   `putClientProperty("iosHideToolbar", Boolean.TURE)` for the TextField.
>   However, there is no keyboard Done option, so the user cannot close
>   the keyboard after entering the value.

Are you sure?

I tried the following code on iOS 13 (iPhone X):

```
Form hi = new Form("Example", BoxLayout.y());
hi.add("Enter a decimal value:");
TextField textField = new TextField();
textField.setConstraint(TextArea.DECIMAL);
hi.add(textField);
hi.add(new Button("Submit"));
hi.show();
```

Result:

[image]

As you can see, this sample code produces the "Done" button on iOS. So, if your app doesn't show it, maybe the cause of the issue is elsewhere.

> I just noticed that there is no Done button shown for a multi-line
>   TextField with normal text

I tried:

```
Form hi = new Form("Example", BoxLayout.y());
hi.add("Enter a multiline text:");
TextArea textField = new TextArea("", 3, 80);
textField.setConstraint(TextArea.ANY);
hi.add(textField);
hi.add(new Button("Submit"));
hi.show();
```

Result:

[image]

Also in this case, there is the "Done" button.

Currently, as far as I know, the "Done" button is not shown in the iOS virtual keyboard toolbar if it's already included in the keyboard itself, for example in the case of a generic `TextField` without a "next" `TextField`. I mean like in the following screenshot *(note that the blue key "fine" is the Italian equivalent of "Done")*:

[image]

So, I don't know how to help you. Try to update your question (or try to open a new one) adding a self-enclosed test case that reproduces your issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your through answer Francesco and sorry not answering sooner (I haven't build on the device for some time). It is really strange because I now tried adding exactly the same fields you've sown, and I still don't get the Done. I also tried changing the iOS keyboard setting in case that was the reason, no luck. However, I now saw your note above "I just noticed that there is no Done button shown for a multi-line TextField with normal text" which seems to contradict your examples - could you elaborate?

Comment: Coming back to this: what I've seen is that when a TextField is the *only* input field in a Form the Done button is shown in the iOS virtual keyboard. But if there are other input fields (seems not to matter whether they are before or after the TextField), there is no Done. I cannot find this documented anywhere in CN1 docs and I would really appreciate to understand how to control this (basically force the Done button even if there are other input fields). Anyone suggestions or paths I can explore?

Comment: I have the suspect that your issue is releated to the tabIndex, that is documented here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/right-sidemenu-tab-order.html#_input_cycle So, try to invoke `.setTraversable(false)` on all your textFields, hopefully every textField will have a Done button. I'm curious to know if it works.

Comment: Thanks again Francesco, very kind of you to provide feedback. I tried that now but it doesn't have a lot of effect (seems setting traversable false simple makes 'next' skip the field). I experimented more, but seem to get all kind of behaviors, depending on I don't know what. I'm a bit tired of spending so much time (since only testable on a device) on what should be straightforward, so I filed an RFE hoping the CN1 team will document how this works: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3126